# How do you block Copy/paste between Linux XRDP server and Windows RDP client?

Tags: linux, windows, security, group-policy, xrdp

We're allowing users to open xrdp sessions with Windows as client, and Linux as the xrdp server.
My requirement is to eliminate the copy pasting going on through this to comply with policies.

If it were Windows -> Windows then you set up a GPO... but group policy doesn't affect the Linux hosts.

Is there another way to block copy paste?

Comment: People can shop without copy and paste. Why don’t you use networking equipment to filter and block websites on the Linux side.

Comment: Hi we need to make sure they cant copy data from the internet (Linux xrdp server side has internet) to their workstation (private net) and vice versa... I'm just citing one example

Comment: There is third-party software that protects data theft. Just disabling copy and pasting of text won’t prevent data theft.

Comment: Yes good thinking. For now, I have been required to comply with a policy set in place by an external governing body and need to block copy/paste.

Comment: [Have you tried launching the sessions with copy and paste disabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/491198/how-to-disable-copypaste-in-azure-ubuntu-machine.html#:~:text=For%20Copy%20%2B%20Paste%20in%20a%20Desktop%20environment%2C,the%20Clipboard%20disabled%20with%3A%20rdesktop%20-r%20clipboard%3Aoff%20XRDPSERVER)

Comment: @Ramhound Looks like that link, rdesktop command was suggested but it doesnt exist on Windows. However I found /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini has cliprdr setting. Just set it to false and copy paste is gone... Im not sure how I couldnt find it on google

Comment: I simply searched "Disabled copy and paste XRDP" and provided a link to the first result I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` has `cliprdr` setting. Just set it to `false` and copy paste is gone.

(Copied from the OP's comment on his own question to make this solution easily visible and mark the question as answered.)